How to open an old showerhead handle without screws
My showerhead is leaking. I can not open the attached handle. There is no screw. Please let me know how to open it? Do you know what is the name or branch? Thanks.

they must have assembled it somehow

I am guessing that the outpost section (the chrome cap) is a press fit and can be popped off. But that is strictly a guess.

Second guess is that the cap screws on, but I like the press fit idea better.

Thanks. But there is no gap or edge to pop it out.

There almost certainly is a gap between the chrome and the gold. It’s just that it’s had years to crust up, so it might be difficult to open. As terrible as it sounds, I’d go at this (gently!) with a chisel.

Any chance the entire ass'y rotates, and there's a set screw under the escutcheon plate?

Thanks all. It still does not work.
